# Is this too much data for an AJAX request?

Tags: java, ajax, jersey

I have a 20-column grid with anywhere from 100 to 1,000 rows.

If each cell averages 50 characters, I would estimate that a 1000-row grid would consist of 20x50x1000 characters = 1MB.

The data for this grid has to be returned by the server in one (or more) AJAX requests. The grid is un-editable... it is just a way of representing a lot of information (about human genes, in particular).

I am having a hard time deciding whether I should return this in one AJAX request or several. Do you think this is too much data (1MB) to return in the XML/JSON response of one AJAX request? Is this an anti-pattern? Or does it make sense seeing how all the data is logically part of one grid?

This is more of a design question than anything else. I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200973/better-many-small-ajax-request-or-a-big-one-for-global-site-performance

Answer (score 1):

Could you not load all the data once using a non-Ajax request and then update only the cells that change via Ajax?

Comment: Ah, the data is based on genes. The user in general selects anywhere from 100 to 1000 genes. But it's not always the same genes, so I couldn't pre-load the data.

Comment: Does the server know what these 100 to 1000 genes are? If so you could just assign an id to each one. Then you only have to Ajax over an array of IDs, which the server can map back to the actual data.

Comment: We don't know what the genes will be until the user selects them. There's something like 20k+ genes in the human genome, and the user can select any number of them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it would interesting keeping the grid "state" in the server so after each field is edited you send the new contents to the server. That would increase the server usage and bandwidth used, but would make it more responsive when the user sends the "submit" command. This also will allow faster input validation (showing an error message almost after the user has modified a cell, and not half hour later).

As an improvement to be in the safe side, keep in memory (JS memory) a list of "dirty" (modified) fields and reset the value when its related ajax response tells you that the server has ack'ed the ajax call; when the user hits "submit" all fields still dirty are sent again to the server.

That said, as long as you stay away from XML, I do not think it is a load so heavy (of course that will depend of hardware and the concurrent users that you have to service).

Comment: Oh I should have been clearer. The grid isn't editable. It's only for viewing annotations about genes (the biological pathways, the associated diseases, developmental processes, et cetera). It's just a way of conveying a lot of information.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you fetch the data in batches. i.e, fetch the first 20-25 rows, or just enough to fill the viewport, then gradually load the next batch as the user scrolls through or when he nears the end of the previous batch. That might make it seamless.

Fetching all the data at once might not be an option considering the number of records you might have.

Furthermore, it's not about too much data, it's about the time it takes to fetch that data. I can guarantee you that (according to how you manipulate the json response), the browser can handle any amount of data.