# Ajax update multiple UI Elements - best practices

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, user-interface

I am currently developing a web-based application which features an user interface, that needs to get updated when a user selects an option from a drop-down menu. This may happen in a cascaded way such as:

1. User picks an option from first select-field
2. GUI is updated and presents additional select fields to choose from (eg. refine category)
3. User refines selection, this may leed to another update etc.

I am using jquery to load the updated pieces from the server.
Up to now I only needed to update one "piece/block" of the interface at a time, and I tried to minimize the amount of data being transferd - so if I only needed to update a select box, I used

```
$(document).on("change",'select[name="first_level_select_field"]',function(){
    $.get('/ajax/handler.php',{"action" : "get_second_level", 
                "first_level_value" : $(this).val()})
    .error(function(data,msg,text){
        alert("Request failed:"+data+","+msg+':'+text);
    })
    .success(function(data,status,text){
        $('select[name="first_level_select_field"]').html(data);
    });
});
```

As you can see, the server side creates a "ready-made" html-piece which is inserted into the second level select box. Same happens for other user interactions.

Now I came across a new use case which requires me to update not only a single select field but also to display an appropriate hint to the user. First solution was to make another ajax-request to the server to fetch the information (again an piece of HTML) and insert into the GUI in the right place.
While this certainly works, I was wondering if I am doing it "right" - some thoughts came to me:

1. Is making multiple requests a good idea or should I create a "package" (eg. wrap up the pieces in a JSON-array) and process it on the client side
2. For more complex GUIs: Is it better to use some kind of container element and update the whole container each time (which simplifies the code on the client side, but introduces additional latency and increases the amount of data to be transfered)

Any suggestion and discussion is welcome - maybe its just another case of TIMTOWTDI and any solution that produces the correct result is ok.

Answer (score 0):

My personal approach to this problem would be to have your handler.php file deliver you a single new form element which includes the hint/tooltip. This keeps AJAX requests down and allows your server to do some of the logic.

Essentially, instead of this:

```
<select class="my_form">
    <option> 1</option>
    .
    .
</select>
```

You may have the php function return this:

```
<div class="custom_form">
    <div class="form_hint>YOUR HINT</div>
    <select>
    .
.
</div>
```

As for the more complex GUI updates, I think that sort of thing is usually best handled by a MVC-style app framework (backbone.js, RoR, etc...). If you *really* wanted to do it with jQuery, I doubt you would want to update the whole form every time.

Comment: I like the idea of using a container-div to hold the whole information, however, this will not work in my case, where I have a given layout, which I am not allowed to alter in such a way so I will have to insert the information "in pieces" ..

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this thread: [Better Many Small Ajax Request Or A Big One For Global Site Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200973/better-many-small-ajax-request-or-a-big-one-for-global-site-performance) the problem seems similar.

To rephrase the answer there: it depends on how the users are expected to use the page. Will these ajax requests be frequent or not? Can you predict some of the users' choices or not?

Some ideas:

- You can prefetch some data (such as select choice list) as soon as the page loads up.
- You can load them in background in intervals.
- Mix. You can preload the data you expect the users to need the most frequently, and fetch the rest as the need arises.

Remember that every ajax request creates an overhead (headers etc). If there are many small requests, total overhead might be not worth it.

Also, if you want your site to get rid of of the load times (and users' waiting), it's better to preload as much as you can.

Concerning your specific dilemma, I personally would preload the set of the choices and hints.

Comment: Preloading is the way to go for the simple cases, thanks for pointing me in this direction. I will also give it a spin for some of the more complex case I have to address eg. when the information or form elements depend on more than just one select field and the rendering is rather complex